# Speeding up BlockMap and Total for 2D array

Tags: performance-tuning

I am optimizing the performance of my code, in a snippet I use lengthy 2D lists that involve `BlockMap` and `Total` function.

For example, for a very large list:

```
list = Table[i, {i, 1, 10^4}, {j, 1, 10^4}];
```

My computation is like this:

```
BlockMap[Total[#, 2] &, list, {3,3}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

The timing result running on my PC is 7 sec.Which is not very quick I guess.

I am wondering if there is any other robust and efficient way to improve the speed. As fast as it could. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my attempt to vectorize the operation.

```
list = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10^4, 10^4}];

a = BlockMap[Total[#, 2] &, list, {3, 3}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = Nest[
     With[{n = Length[#] - Mod[Length[#], 3]},
       Transpose@
        Plus[#[[1 ;; n ;; 3]], #[[2 ;; n ;; 3]], #[[3 ;; n ;; 3]]]
       ] &,
     list,
     2
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a == b
```

> 13.8097
>
> 1.41927
>
> True

I also found a second one, involving a `SparseArray` and matrix-matrix-multiplication. You can also specify the block size.

```
ClearAll[f];
f[list_?MatrixQ, {d1_, d2_}] := Module[{A, B},
   {A, B} = MapThread[
     {n, d} \[Function] With[{m = Quotient[n, d]},
       SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {n, m}, 0, {1, {
           Join[Range[0, d m], ConstantArray[d m, n - d m]], 
           Partition[ Join @@ Transpose[{Range[1, m]}[[ConstantArray[1, d]]]], 1]}, ConstantArray[1, d m]}}
       ],
     {Dimensions[list], {d1, d2}}];
   Dot[Dot[Transpose[A], list], B]
   ];

c = f[list, {3, 3}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a == b == c
```

> 0.200843
>
> True

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the input! I like the second solution, however, the issue is the dimension of `list`, in some cases, it not working. For example, it is working when `list = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {121, 121}];` but when the dimension equals {120,120} it's not. I couldn't figure out the reason.

Comment: Hope I found the error. Please try again.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simpler (to me) version of @Henrik's [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) approach:

```
sa = PadRight[
    KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[3333, SparseArray], Table[1,3]],
    {3333,10^4}
]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 = sa . list . Transpose[sa]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = f[list, {3, 3}]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 == r2
```

> {0.00014, Null}
>
> {0.197, Null}
>
> {0.202, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Argh! You're so right! I really should remember this `KroneckerProduct` trick.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Feel free to update your answer to use KroneckerProduct and I will delete my answer. I debated commenting on your answer vs writing a new one, and narrowly ended up deciding to write an answer.

Comment: Everything is fine. Let it as it is. It's just not the first time that I learn about this use of `KroneckerProduct`. =)

Answer (score 4):

`ListConvolve` seems a bit faster, even though you need to discard about 88% of its output:

```
list = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {10^4, 10^4}];

(bmr = BlockMap[Total[#, 2] &, list, {3, 3}]); // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {11.6426, Null}
> ```

```
(lcr = ListConvolve[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, list][[1 ;; -1 ;; 3, 1 ;; -1 ;; 3]]); // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {4.76819, Null}
> ```

```
lcr == bmr
```

> ```
> True
> ```